# What is the significance of a batch size of greater than one?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Why do we use batch sizes in neural networks and deep learning methods such as ConvNets?
I mean rather than taking average of several steps and going in that direction which causes smoother movement in the parameter space, what are the benefits that we gain by doing this?
Does using batch-size=1 affect the performance badly? does using more batch-size translate to faster convergence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommend to read "Neural Networks: Tricks of the trade", all reason to improve parameter tuning are precisely describe in the book. And to your specific questions:

*What are the benefits that we gain by doing this?*

- As you said, most benefit from "smoother movement in parameter space"
- Parallel processing of multiple batches.

*Does using batch-size=1 affect the performance badly?*

- No, not as significantly as you think, just like gradient update without momentum term.

*Does using more batch-size translate to faster convergence?*

- More batch-size doesn't always lead to faster convergence, but instead, gradient update can be more stable.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very good :)
would you elaborate more on the gradient update to be more stable? what exactly does that mean in practice? (I mean intuitively )

Comment: Gradient updates don't always go to the same direction when you train it a single data sample, but with a "batch" of them, the update goes to the more reasonable direction you wanted. I learned a lot by reading this page https://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs449/momrate.html though it only illustrated about momentum term.

Answer (score 1):

1. Performance usually drops with batch_size=1 if you supply your batch with python which usually 100+ slower than c code and preparing you batch usually done with batch operations (numpy)

2.From result standpoint the more batch size it is the closer it to real gradient (rather than stochastic) which can be desirable and faster coverage, but in neral networks usually a lot of local minimums so you want that randomness in gradient to get away from them. Thats why Limited-memory BFGS usually not work for NN.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in one of stanfords cnn courses, the teacher says, the local minimus in CNns are not that of a big deal as they are in normal NNs? How is that? 
apart from that, from your answer I conclude that a batch of 50 is better than a batch of 100 right? since it provides more randomness ?

Comment: As far as convolutional neural networks are concerned, batching should not improve the compute time by vectorizing the code. Convolution operation is already a big load for the machine to do, so most of the time computer spends is in C. That being said, what you say is very true for standard feed-forward neural networks, where the computation is just a small matrix multiplication for each layer.